# Parsing Postman JSON collection file to create a C# REST client test?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, postman

I'm looking into how I can create a Postman collection parser. While working with it, I started wondering if someone else has dealt with the same question.

The reason why I'd want to create a parser, is to be able to create automated tests that can be used in a deployment tool (such as Octopus Deploy). Our test data has a tendency to change a lot, so we can't make reliable static tests which will last a while, so having a way to change tests on the go would solve at least this issue for REST services.

The closest I got, is this dead(?) project
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Api.Postman/

Comment: You want to parse a collection so that you can run the tests via HttpClient or something like in a console app?

Comment: I've started making a parser by making my own v2.10 collection object as well as RestSharp as the REST client. But not sure if my approach is the best though.

I saw that there's a postman SDK for npm, but not for C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Newman (NPM package) to create and test postman stuff

[Newman - companion to Postman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman)